# How to reflect another project's class info

Tags: java, eclipse

there are two projects in eclipse! how to reflect one class in other project? I put other project's class path into system's property. but still popup class not found exception. Is there any good solution for it?

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.class.path"));        

System.getProperties().put("java.class.path",
    System.getProperty("java.class.path") +
        ";C:\\Users\\fu.jian\\workspace\\Study\\bin");

System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.class.path"));

Class<?> forName2 = Class.forName("study.Activator");
System.out.println(forName2);
```

Comment: not work: Properties extends Hashtable. put or set is same for map.

Comment: not work. you mean this?'System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.class.path")); Properties properties = System.getProperties(); properties.setProperty("java.class.path", properties.getProperty("java.class.path")+";C:\\Users\\fu.jian\\workspace\\Study\\bin"); System.setProperties(properties); System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.class.path")); Class<?> forName2 = Class.forName("study.Activator"); System.out.println(forName2);'

Comment: URL[] urls = new URL[] { new URL(
    "file:/C:/Users/fu.jian/workspace/Study/bin/") };
  
   URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(urls);
  Class<?> loadClass = loader.loadClass("study.Activator");

  System.out.println(loadClass);

Answer (score 2):

Right click the project to bring up the context menu.

**Build Path->Configure Build Path**

Under the **Java Build Path** dialog, select the **Projects** tab and add the project.

Comment: 3ks, I know this solution. In fact. it will be considered as one project. My initial goal is complete it without manual operation.

Comment: URL[] urls = new URL[] { new URL(
    "file:/C:/Users/fu.jian/workspace/Study/bin/") };
  
   URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(urls);
  Class<?> loadClass = loader.loadClass("study.Activator");

  System.out.println(loadClass);

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the project B to classpath of project A by:

In *Eclipse* click on project A -> mouse right click and select *Properties* -> Select *Java Build Path* -> Select *Projects* tab -> Click on *Add...* and check project B

The problem will be resolved inside Eclipse, if you use external tools for compilation and building the project - your problem will still appear.
You can export the project B as jar and copy the jar into the project A libs. This way you won't depend on Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your answer is similer with aboved replay. Get the goal through becoming one project. But I think if any place to modify the classpaths to load the class. dude

Comment: URL[] urls = new URL[] { new URL(
    "file:/C:/Users/fu.jian/workspace/Study/bin/") };
  
   URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(urls);
  Class<?> loadClass = loader.loadClass("study.Activator");

  System.out.println(loadClass);

Comment: To put them in one project is best because you will avoid the problem. In case you still want to load a class from another place, I'm sure you can do with URLCLassLoader. Even it is very inelegant soluton.